# Git command to show author, comment and lines modified

Tags: git

I am using git command: `git log --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit --all --pretty --oneline`. I like the formating it gives me, but I am missing a lot of information, how should I include author and lines/files modified?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

This will be better look

`git log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --shortstat`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git log --graph --shortstat --abbrev-commit --date=short --pretty=format:'%h [%an] [%ad] %s'
```

Comment: does not give any results

Answer (score 0):

i use the following

```
git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%Cblue\\ [%cn]" --decorate --numstat
```